# can a listfield in blackberry be divided into 2 halves?

Tags: blackberry

i am developing a simple calculator application in blackberry now, and i am new to that environment.
i want to develop an application(calculator) which runs in a list like. probably there will be more simpler ways for implementing this. but i want to study with my stuff.

```
value1    : (numeric textfield)
value1    : (numeric textfield)

+         : (result(value1+value2))
-         : (result(value1-value2))
*         : (result(value1*value2))
/         : (result(value1/value2))
```

for this application, I have developed using eclipse as..

```
public class Scr_Main extends MainScreen
{

    String my_array[] = new String[]{"+", "-", "*","/"};
    EditField editfield_value1,editfield_value2;
    ObjectListField my_list;
    GridFieldManager gfm;

    public Scr_Main()
    {
        this.setTitle("Address Book");
        //Defining Components 

        gfm = new GridFieldManager(1, 1, 0);
        editfield_value1 = new EditField("Enter Value :", "");
        add(gfm);

            gfm = new GridFieldManager(1, 1, 0);
        editfield_value2 = new EditField("Enter Value :", "");
        add(gfm);

        my_list= new ObjectListField();
        my_list.set(my_array);
        add(my_list);
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can i divide the list into two halves. or do i need to add one more list? or is there any way a list to be divided into two halves?

Comment: If you work out a custom painting of each list row, you could paint what you want on it. Otherwise create buttons and arrange them into managers so you get a 2x2 table. I'd go for the buttons option, since even if you paint 2 items per row in ObjectListField, the click event will report only one click per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `ListFieldCallback.drawListRow()` method to customise the way each row is painted.

Comment: thank you for helping me. but my problem still exists. i am search for how i can design my listview according to my concept. But ur reply was really helping. i had gone on that way. :)

Comment: what are you still having a problem with?

Comment: ya, still i hadnt got is as i needed. as u guided i had override the ListFieldCallBack. and in that drawListRow i want to add two labels in a row. had tried it, but not getting as a asked. is there anyway to add two labels in drawlistrow? if possible, just demonstrate it for me...